# Consistency of estimators

Tags: estimation, consistency

For $1\leq i\leq K$, I have an estimator of $\mu_{i}$ given by $\hat{\mu}_{i}=\frac{1}{K}\sum_{j\neq i=1}^{K}\frac{Y_{ij}}{n_{ij}}$, where $Y_{ij}\sim N(n_{ij}(\mu_{i}-\mu_{j}),\sigma^{2}n_{ij})$. What would a sequence of estimators of $\mu_{i}$ based on $\hat{\mu}_{i}$ and $n=\sum_{i,j}n_{ij}$ look like in order to consider their consistency or other properties ?

Comment: What is expectation of $\hat \mu_i$, i.e., $E(\hat\mu_i) = ?$

Comment: It is an unbiased estimator.

Comment: Could you check it to see if it is really unbiased?

Comment: Yes, I have checked it. The $\mu_{i}$'s are subject to the constraint $\sum_{i=1}^{K}\mu_{i}=0$. I need to check consistency and other properties for which a sequence of such estimators is required.

Comment: But in your question, I did not find any hint about that constraint.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to include the constraint in the original question. Also, $Y_{ij}$'s are independent r.v.'s.